# Html select option change color text

Tags: php, jquery

A have a table named `Systems(id, name)`. I send a query `SELECT * FROM Systems WHERE id = SPECIFIC_ID`. Then I have another query `SELECT  * FROM Systems WHERE id  != SPECIFIC_ID`.

I display them all in a html select like this:

```
<select id="select">
<option value="'.$row1["id"].'">'.$row1["name"].'</option> // this is the result of the first query
while () {
    //the result of the second query
}
</select>
```

Now I would like to have the first option colored red. Now I tried to use jQuery code I found on stackoveflow:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#select').css('color','gray');
    $('#select').change(function() {
       var current = $('#select').val();
       if (current != 'null') {
           $('#select').css('color','black');
       } else {
           $('#select').css('color','gray');
       }
    }); 
});
```

This is how the code above works: http://jsfiddle.net/fMQeq/

But to use it, you need to have a specific value. In my case, the value isn't static. How can I color that option?

Comment: Why not add a style property in php code?

Comment: You are never setting the colour to red, only black or grey?

Comment: @Doodlebunch I tried, but it didn't work.

Comment: i don't think you can change color of _option_ tag

Comment: It's always the first option? And, if you want to use JavaScript (or jQuery) show the rendered HTML, not the php.

Comment: @JohnathanBrown I'm not an idiot, I copied the code straight from the site...

Comment: @DavidThomas yes, but when I select another option and then return to the first one, I would like to have it colored red anyway. HTML or PHP code isn't relevant in that case, I just want to figure out the jQuery way to color the option.

Answer (score 0):

Option tag itself cannot be set style on it.

But you can make an alternative approach to this target:

Just make a dropdown `div` including all the `option` elements, and set the click event for it, after click, change the `<select>` tag value. And then hide the `<select>` tag.

Answer (score 0):

Can you try it for an example?

```
    <style>
    .gray{
        background-color:#f00;
        border:2px solid #f00;
        color:#f00;
    }
    .black{
        background-color:#000;
        border:2px solid #000;
    }
    </style>
```

HTML

```
    <select id="select">
    <option value="">--Select --</option> // this is the result of the first query
    <option value="1">One</option> // this is the result of the first query
    </select>
```

SCRIPT

```
    <script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $('#select').attr('color','gray');
        $('#select').change(function() {
           var current = $('#select').val();
           if (current == "") {
               $('#select').attr('class','black');
           } else {
               $('#select').attr('class','gray');
           }
        }); 
    });
    </script>
```

Comment: I cannot set `value=""` because I need to send the system's id for other operations.

Comment: you have given something like this ... if (current != 'null') ... thats why I kept if (current == '')

Answer (score 0):

Use raw css

```
select:nth-child(1){
    color:red;
}
```

And you wont need to put ID there

Answer (score 0):

You can do that :)
It's not impossible to put css code directly in your html.

```
<p><a href="http://www.korben.info/42" style="font-size:10px"><font color="red">YEAH</font></a>
```